# Pagination don’t list all entries on Index.php

Tags: pagination

Pagination **works perfect on pages** but **not on the Index**.php
Problem: It doesn’t list all entries and the Count for Entries beyond settings >> reading interferes. Depending from what I setting the Count, Entries missing or it list too much empty pages in the Pagination-list at the end…

This is what I did:

````
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
else { $paged = 1; }
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 4 ,
  'category_name'=> 'Allgemein',
  'post_status' => 'publish, future',
  'order'=> 'DEC',
  'orderby'=> 'date',
  'paged'=> $paged
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);?>
<?php the_content(); ?> <?php endforeach; ?>

<div><?php the_posts_pagination( array(
    'mid_size' => 4,
     
    'prev_text' => __( '←', 'textdomain' ),
    'next_text' => __( '→', 'textdomain' ),
) ); ?></div>```

Thanks for any help & solution

PS: The post_status future will be shown by using a function “show_future_posts”, as I want to have a special Entry always first.
````

Comment: Is your all entries only indicate condition with category_name is Allgemein,post_status is publish, future, and it miss some entry correspond with those 2 condition?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `new WP_Query` on index.php. Look at the index.php templates of the default themes to see how to do the loop correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both.
Meanwhile I got it to work perfect.  **The way** was done with **pre_get_posts**.

My solution now is the function:

````
function numberposts_for_index( $query ) {
if( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() && $query->is_home() ) {
$query->set( 'posts_per_page', '4' );
$query->set('post_status','future,publish');
}}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'numberposts_for_index' );```


and my code in the index.php now:

```<?php 
if(have_posts()) :
    while(have_posts())  : the_post();?>
<?php the_content('<br />→ weiterlesen …'); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div><?php the_posts_pagination( array(
    'mid_size' => 4,
    'prev_text' => __( '←', 'neuere Beiträge' ),
    'next_text' => __( '→', 'ältere Beiträge' ),
) ); ?></div><p>&nbsp;</p>
        <?php else :?>
<h3><?php _e('404 Error: Not Found', ''); ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>```
````